# Alternative for nested forms

Tags: html, forms, view, codeigniter-2

I need nested forms. I know that they are not allowed in HTML, so I decided to set several submit buttons for one opened form.

In my controller I need to check which of the submit buttons is pressed. How can I do that?

I'm trying to give buttons names like this:

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" name="editAction" type="submit" value="Save"></button>
```

Then in my controller I check them like this:

```
if ($this->input->post('editAction'))
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are bound to have several `submit buttons` in your `form`, then you can do 2 things :

1) Convert `submit buttons` into `normal buttons` and submit form using `ajax`. This will solve your problem.

2) Convert submit buttons into normal buttons and maintain a hidden field on your form and `onClick` event of all buttons, just put the `id` of the button in that hidden field as a value, and then using `jQuery`, submit your form and then in your `controller`, check your hidden field value and then process the form.

```
if ($this->input->post('hidden_field_name'))
```